# Grails IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: grails, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following code in Grails:

```
public LibraryItem createLibraryItemWithValues(ProjectItem projectItem) {
    def libraryitem = new LibraryItem ()
    libraryitem.name = projectItem.name
    libraryitem.itemtype = projectItem.itemtype.itemtype
    libraryitem.description = projectItem.description
    List<LibraryCategoryValue> libCatValues = new ArrayList<LibraryCategoryValue>();
    for (def pcv : projectItem.categoryvalues) {
        libCatValues.add(pcv.librarycategoryvalue);
    }
    if (libraryitem.id != null && !libraryitem.isAttached()) {
        libraryitem.attach()
    }
    libCatValues.each{
        it.addToLibraryitems(libraryitem)
    }
    return libraryitem.save()
}
```

The class LibraryCategoryValue

```
package ch.fhnw.accelerom.project.library

import ch.fhnw.accelerom.project.ItemType
import ch.fhnw.accelerom.project.TranslatableObject


class LibraryCategoryValue extends TranslatableObject {
  SortedSet<LibraryItem> libraryitems

  static belongsTo = [librarycategory:LibraryCategory]
  static hasMany = [libraryitems: LibraryItem]
  static constraints = {
  }
}
```

My problem is, that I get the exception "IndexOutOfBoundsException" with the detailMessage "Index:1, Size 0" and suppressedExceptions "Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList" with Value "size = 0" when I run this code in the service but there is no exception, when I run this code in the controller. The exception comes from the command it.addToLibraryitems(libraryitem), respektive, when I comment this line, than no exception occur. Can someone give me a hint, what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I now initialized libraryitems in the class with

```
SortedSet<LibraryItem> libraryitems = []
```

but now I get the following error when I start the application

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectch.fhnw.accelerom.project.library.LibraryCategoryValue
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectch.fhnw.accelerom.project.library.LibraryCategoryValue
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectch.fhnw.accelerom.project.library.LibraryCategoryValue
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectch.fhnw.accelerom.project.library.LibraryCategoryValue
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectch.fhnw.accelerom.project.library.LibraryCategoryValue
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'java.util.SortedSet' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.SortedSet()
    at ch.fhnw.accelerom.project.library.LibraryCategoryValue.<init>(LibraryCategoryValue.groovy:7)
    ... 4 more
```

Edit 2:

I also tried to initialize libraryitems with

```
SortedSet<LibraryItem> libraryitems = new TreeSet<LibraryItem>()
```

But then I'm back on the first exception "IndexOutOfBoundsException". I'm so wondering, why there is no problem, when this code is in the controller. What's the difference between a service and a controller in this case?

Comment: Show code of domain `LibraryCategoryValue`. Moreover did you try to `libraryitem.save()` before `libCatValues.each{...}`?

Comment: libraryitem.save() before libCatValues.each{...} doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.3.7

Comment: I would recommend initialising the `libraryitems` with `[] as SortedSet`. Not sure if this is causing your problem, but Collections that can be `null` are always dangerous

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused how to do this. Could you write line?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a transactional service method:

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional

class LibraryService {

    @Transactional
    public LibraryItem createLibraryItemWithValues(ProjectItem projectItem) {
        def libraryitem = new LibraryItem()

        libraryitem.name = projectItem.name
        libraryitem.itemtype = projectItem.itemtype.itemtype
        libraryitem.description = projectItem.description

        projectItem.categoryvalues*.librarycategoryvalue.each {
            it.addToLibraryitems(libraryitem)
        }

        return libraryitem.save()
    }
}
```

Since you're creating a new `LibraryItem` it's ID will always be null until you save it. In most cases you don't need to use `attach()`, so I removed all of that code.

Comment: I tryed your hint, but I still get the same exception. As side note, the class "ItemService", in which the method "createLibraryItemWithValue" is, is already defined @Transactional.